# syntax error when trying to input date and time

Tags: sql, sqlite

I just started with SQL and I'm having a problem when trying to insert an date and time.

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Voo_Pac 
(
     codReserva INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     DataCont DATE,
     HoraCont TIME
);
```

Code I'm trying to use to insert date and time:

```
INSERT INTO Voo_Pac (codReserva, DataCont, HoraCont)
VALUES (1), (15-08-2019), (12:13:52);
```

When I try to execute the code, it gives me the following message:

> Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near ":13": syntax error)

Comment: what's your rdbms? oracle,sqlserver?

Comment: i'm usign w3schools SQL Tryit Editor

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.  [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: it's sqlite rdbms,i help you to add the tag

Comment: *"i'm usign w3schools SQL Tryit Editor "* i would suggest if you want to learn SQL, install a server like SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQLite local and look in the official vendor manuals not test or learn from a website which had the name w3fools in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using MySQL/MariaDB/SQL Server because of the `TIME` datatype?

Your insert should be

```
INSERT INTO Voo_Pac (codReserva, DataCont, HoraCont)
VALUES (1, '2019-08-15', '12:13:52');
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/voXFZaEaxecsETfDNvL731/0)

Answer (score 0):

You at least need quotes. And depending on your DB maybe a CAST to the apropiated type

```
INSERT INTO Voo_Pac (codReserva, DataCont, HoraCont)
VALUES 1, '15-08-2019', '12:13:52';
```

Comment: then you need convert the date . but we dont know what is your db. Is oracle, mysql postgres?

Comment: i'm using w3schools SQL Tryit Editor